# Emmet Plugin não funciona dentro de html tags

Tags: ide, phpstorm, webstorm

Boas.
Eu acabei de instalar o emmet plugin no WebStorm, e funciona tudo bem, exceto quando tento utilizar o emmet dentro de uma   tag por exemplo, onde nem as sugestões ou live templates aparecem como deviam.
Quando vejo alguém a utilizaro  plugin eles não tem este problema.
Alguma ideia? Thanks.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Descreva melhor o seu problema e apresente exemplos que possam ser reproduzidos.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo o problema está descrito, basicamente eu faço ul.nome>li*4 e isto gera uma ul com a classe nome e 4 li dentro da ul, e funciona tudo bem, exceto se fizer dentro de uma div tag ou qualquer outra, que não gera nada nem aparece a sugestão. Já coloquei um exemplo do emmet plugin. Obrigado.

Comment: Eu me referia à versão do plugin, IDE e OS

Comment: A versão é emmet 1.2.5

Comment: Já habilitou o html  `File > Settings > Editor > Emmet` ?

Comment: Sim, tem um visto em XML/HTML Emmet, preview da abreviação, reconhecimento  de URL automático e edit point. O que é estranho é não funcionar dentro de tags, só.